# Is setting interval right way to make sure Ajax call is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

I have two input text field and one <kbd>save</kbd> button.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<input type="text" id="searchResult"/>
<button id="myButton>save</button>
```

The `myInput` text field has **onchange event** which then sends Ajax request to get some data and show the result to `searchResult` text field.

The save button has **click event** which validate the input of `searchResult` text field for empty string and such. If ok then proceed with saving.

```
$("myInput").change(function() {
    var userInput = $("myInput").val(); //get value from the text field
    var responseText = callAjaxToGetData(userInput):  //XHR request to get some data

    $("searchResult").val( responseText ); //show the XHR result here

});


$("myButton").click(function() {
    var searchResultField = $("searchResult").val(); //get value from the searchResult field
    var isOK = validate(searchResultField);  //check empty string and such

    if(isOK) { saveDataViaAjax(userInput); }
});
```

**Problem**

When a user types in some text into the text field and then clicks on "`save"` button,

1. `onchange event` is triggered, `callAjaxToGetData()` is called. (XHR)
2. before `callAjaxToGetData()` is completed and fill in the `searchResult` text field, myButton `onclick event` is triggered.
3. In side of `onclick` event handler, validation fails because `searchResult` field is still empty.
4. `callAjaxToGetData()` finally finishes and fill in `searchResult` text field.

Ideally, `callAjaxToGetData()` is completed first then proceed with the process inside of `onclick` event so the validation won't fail.

This seems very common case people would face I guess so I'm wondering how you approach this problem?

I am thinking to put interval into `onclick` event like below (this requires `responseText` to be a global variable)

```
$("myButton").click(function() {

   var interval = setInterval(function() { //call every 500ms

       //if responseText is not null that means i know the ajax inside of onchange event is completed for sure.
       if( responseText != null ) {

           clearInterval(interval);

           var searchResultField = $("searchResult").val(); //get value from the searchResult field
           var isOK = validate(searchResultField);  //check empty string and such
    
           if(isOK) { saveDataViaAjax(userInput); }
       }
   }, 500);  
});
```

Comment: After clicking save, you check if a request is going and wait for it to finish and then call the validate-save function. Another problem could be if you're changing the input too fast, and the requests go into race condition, so you have to stop the first one or ignore it.

Comment: $.active can be an option here..

Answer (score 1):

Code below might not be exact but I'd disable the button before ajax and enable after callback returns.

```
$("myInput").change(function() {
     $("myButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     var userInput = $("myInput").val(); //get value from the text field
     var responseText = callAjaxToGetData(userInput, function(data) {

        $("searchResult").val( data); //show the XHR result here
        $("myButton").removeAttr("disabled"); 
     }):
 });
```

Comment: Do you mean the click event for "myButton" will be fired right after disabled attribute is removed from "myButton" ??? If so I did not know the event trigger timing can be controlled in such way.

Comment: I tried the code above and since button is disabled, the click event won't get triggered after the change event.

Comment: hey, the above code disables the button until the data is received.  Then the button is re-enabled.  (since pressing the button isn't really a valid option until the call returns.)  I hope that helps.

Comment: I know your intention but I tested your code and click event did not fire. The mouse event won't get triggered for disabled element.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to avoid `onClick event` process goes faster than ajax process in `onChange event`, setting timer solved the problem.

First I created helper function which checks active ajax connection and calls function that would be otherwise called in onClick event.

**helper**

```
function check_pending_process(callback) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if($.active > 0) {
            //do nothing here
        }
        else {
            //no ajax is running, call the function after 500 ms
            clearInterval(interval);
            setTimeout(function() { window[callback].call() }, 500);
        }    
    }, 100);
}
```

**caller**

```
function processButtonClick() {
    var searchResultField = $("searchResult").val(); //get value from the searchResult field
    var isOK = validate(searchResultField);  //check empty string and such

    if(isOK) { saveDataViaAjax(userInput); }

}

$("#myButton").click(function() {

    check_pending_process("processButtonClick");

});
```

The 500 ms judgement is based on how long the process of post-ajax in onchange event takes.  In my case, post-ajax process inside of onchange event is just put response text into the text field so 500 ms is enough.